# Making a Mathematica version of Wordle interactive

Tags: dynamic, button, interactive

Just as a diversion, I'd like to create an interactive *Mathematica* version of [Wordle](https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/). As a sketch I have the following:

```
wordlist = 
Import["https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cfreshman/a03ef2cba789d8cf00c08f767e0fad7b/raw/a9e55d7e0c08100ce62133a1fa0d9c4f0f542f2c/wordle-answers-alphabetical.txt", "List"];
word = Characters[RandomSample[wordlist, 1][[1]]];
wordle[string_] := Module[{guess, thread},
guess = Characters[string]; thread = Thread[{word, guess}];
Row[Table[
 If[Length[DeleteDuplicates[thread[[t]]]] == 1, 
  Text[Style[DeleteDuplicates[thread[[t]]][[1]], Large, White, 
    Background -> Darker[Green]]], 
  If[MemberQ[word, guess[[t]]], 
   Text[Style[guess[[t]], Black, Large, Background -> Yellow]], 
   If[MemberQ[word, guess[[t]]] == False, 
    Text[Style[guess[[t]], White, Large, Background -> Gray]], 
    Text[Style[guess[[t]], White, Large, 
      Background -> Black]]]]], {t, 5}]
]];

(*wordle["stead"]*)
```

How can I make this sketch interactive?

Comment: Not a particularly helpful comment - but it might do to explain what Wordle is. I have never heard of it and I just asked my wife, stepdaughter and stepson and they have never heard of it either.

Comment: [Wordle](https://www.powerlanguage.co.uk/wordle/) is a popular word game in which you try to discover a 5-letter word by guessing other 5-letter words, with a mechanic somewhat similar to the schoolroom game hangman.

Comment: A WL Wordle [implementation](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2445356) on the Wolfram Community site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a very minimal interactive wireframe to get you started.

```
DynamicModule[{words = {}, word = ""},
 Column[{
   Dynamic@Column@words,
   Row[{
     InputField[Dynamic[word], String],
     Button["Submit", AppendTo[words, wordle[word]]; word = ""]
     }]}]]
```

[image: Wordle]

Comment: many thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

Feel free to take a look at this on the Wolfram community that I did for fun:

[a facsimile of Wordle](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2445356)

Moderators: update… I did not see that a link to this was added as a comment above. I am leaving this one as well, but feel free to change it to a comment or to delete it as you see fit. Thanks!

Comment: lots of fun to play with, thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks!  Enjoy! I recently added some additional explanatory text to the notebook.

Comment: And here is a small blog post that I was asked to write:  https://blog.wolfram.com/2022/02/04/wordle-the-wolfram-way/